# github action to copy a file from one repo to another

Tags: github, github-actions

my company has created a complex way to move files between environments and now we would like to move certain built JS files (transpiled and minified) from one github repo to another. Is this possible using github actions?

Comment: I believe built files should not be kept in a repository

Comment: @Ziarno
this is a special case

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest option is to clone the target repo, copy the files into the target repo, use the git commandline to stage the files and then commit them. Add the code below in a script step

```
run: |
    git clone https://.:${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}@github.com/project target
    rm everything but the .git directory
    copy source\files target
    cd target
    git add .
    git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -m "Automatic publish from github.com/project"
    git push target master
```

Comment: You may need to store a Personal Access Token to the GitHub secrets store in case the GITHUB_TOKEN doesn't have the correct permissions.

Comment: See this for token permissions: https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/authenticating-with-the-github_token#permissions-for-the-github_token

Comment: What does `rm target` do in this case?  Isn't `target` a directory?

Comment: Yeah, looking at this I think we're missing an -rf here... Just ensuring there is a clean dir to clone into.

Comment: OK good, that makes sense and also do the `rm` before the `clone` or you are removing what you just cloned.  Thanks for the answer and update.

Comment: "rm -rf target" should be before the clone.

Comment: another useful addition is to modify the `git commit` line to handle the case where nothing changes.  If not the action will fail in that case.  `git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit` .  Idea credit: github.com/cpina

Also, is the web address above correct?  What is `//.:` ?

Comment: Yeah that's correct the `.` is the username (which doesn't matter when using a token. After the `:` comes the password (token). You could use `notneeded:` or `github:` if you'd like.

Comment: so this means only  a single person can run this action? that's nonsense. what if 10 people are working on the repo?

Comment: How about using a diff command so you only copy differences between the source and target repo?

Comment: @LeeWhieldon git well always commit the changed files and will automatically push only the missing commits on the other end.