# How do I reference / push a file from one repository when a PR is merged to master to another repository automatically?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a repository where I end up modifying a file (a simple metadata file for the repo) every time I commit to a branch in that repo and merge to master.

I need to copy this metadata file currently to another repository and push it over there. Is it possible, in some way, to reference just this particular metadata file in another repo, perhaps or even automagically copy-and-commit to another repo without me doing it every time(actions/hooks)? The other repo is a collector of metadata from all my repos and it is quite cumbersome every time to copy things

Thanks!

Comment: I came up with these GitHub actions by quick google search. [Push a file to another repository](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/push-a-file-to-another-repository)  and [Push directory to another repository](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/push-directory-to-another-repository).  Plus this SO post : [github action to copy a file from one repo to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59408320/github-action-to-copy-a-file-from-one-repo-to-another) Not sure if they help your cause.

Comment: `git push` sends *commits*, not files. Each commit holds a full snapshot of *every* file (that Git is told to put into that commit, via Git's index). If you want to push a commit that holds just one file, you need to make such a commit (by removing any other files and holding just the one file). There is a method to use a tag with a blob object, to avoid creating a commit, but that's extremely special-case-y; you almost certainly want to use commits here.